# Maintain list data when appending C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I just notice a problem with a function I wrote, I realized the problem but the 'fix' only worsen the situation.

The function connects to my db and makes select query, then it returns any rows as a `List<List<string>>`, the intended behavior was returning 1 `List<string>` for every row and since every row has multiple columns I could access them with the list index.

```
                    try
                    {
                        ///Open connection before we can read
                        dataConnection.Open();

                        ///Prepare to read
                        reader = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

                        // Call Read before accessing data.
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            myTestData.Clear();
                            for (int i = 0; i < howManyColumns; i++)
                            {
                                ///Add columns to myTestData list
                                myTestData.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                            }
                            ///Add myTestData list to dataRows
                            dataRows.Add(myTestData);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException exSql)
                    {
                        Program.displayExError(exSql, true);
                    }
```

The problem is in the line:

```
myTestData.Clear();
```

I tried clearing the list, so the next time I added one list to my list of lists it will have no elements and avoid appending all the rows to the same list, but instead if I do `myTestData.Clear();` the list contents are erased and my List of List looses all its contents too, any ideas to keep the data in without appending to the first list?

PS: The Fix i did was adding `myTestData.Clear();` which is what causes the problem but if I take it off all the rows are appended to the first List and no use as well. If the problem is unclear please let me know to try and clarify

Thx guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new list, rather than `Clear`ing the existing list. Change `mydata.Clear()` to `myData = new List<string>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Think of `myData` as an object reference which you are adding to `dataRows` - when you clear `myData` the reference kept by `dataRows` reflects that very same change.

So you need to simply create a new `List<string>` each time you go to read a row from the datareader.

Comment: I was aware that was the problem, but had no idea of how to fix it, I was trying with temp lists till I got the answer here thx!

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess and say you have to re-initialize the list in the for loop so instead of

```
myTestData.Clear();
```

try

```
myTestData = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I amuse your `List<List<string>>` is called dataRows from the example.

Rather than clearing the list, which will still add the reference to the dataRows list you could create a new list and store it:

```
try
{
  ///Open connection before we can read
  dataConnection.Open();

  ///Prepare to read
  reader = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

  // Call Read before accessing data.
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    List<string> myTestData = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < howManyColumns; i++)
    {
      ///Add columns to myTestData list
      myTestData.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
    }
    ///Add myTestData list to dataRows
    dataRows.Add(myTestData);
  }
}
catch (SqlException exSql)
{
  Program.displayExError(exSql, true);
}
```